# Dynamical model fields in django

Tags: django, models

I want that objects of one model(Thing, list of everyday things, variable length) will be fields of model Day(date, thing1, thing2, ...). It's possible?

If it's not possible, i will use Day(date, fk->Thing), but how in Django admin interface i may list table, where in column - no of exercise repeats and in row - dates and how edit repeats of all exercises in day?

sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

read about `TabularInline` in [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) or [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/)